# Best settings for MySQL to speed up site?

Tags: mysql, performance, options

What are the best settings for MySQL to speed up a WordPress site?

Comment: Even assuming any setting of MySQL would have been important to wordpress performance (which for 99% of the sites is not) to answer this type of question requires some background about the usage scenario. Setting for a mostly read only server will be different from a server with massive amount of write.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no best MySQL settings for WordPress, it may be very different from site to site. [This article](http://wordpresswebmaster.net/mysql-database-optimization-on-wordpress/) could serve you as starting point to optimize the settings for your site.

Answer (score 0):

Speed up a wordpress site is not a MySQL settings issue. One site in order to perform well is to **USE** MySQL with the best efficient way (limit your queries results, get only what you need)

Default wordpress database schema have been already set up (primary keys, indexes e.t.c) to be used by the default scripts (e.x. WP_Query) with the more efficient way.

The best thing to do if you own a low performance wp site is to check the server itself (you can install many plugins to monitor you php and mysql performance) and if you are pretty sure that is not a script issue that causes the latency then contact with your hosting provider in order to check your machine.

Now if you are using custom queries in your wordpress installation you must always have in mind the default db schema because it is very easy to create a slow (sometimes very slow) custom query.